# rails 4 how to configure ckeditor 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I wan't to use the CKEditor in my Rails-App.

in my gemfile I added this line

```
gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git'
```

after i run "bundle update" and "rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip" I add to my application.js this line:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

in my view I added this line:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :img, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'img', :customConfig => asset_path('ckeditor/config.js')} %>
```

I created this folders and files:

```
/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor
/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js
/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/contents.css
```

My config.js looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar_img = [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    ]
}
```

Why my Editor looks like this?
[image: ckeditor]

Comment: What were you expecting it to be?

Comment: why it has so many toolbars? I wan't to have only the New Page and Preview Button :)

Comment: Where do you see 'New Page' and 'Preview button' in CKEditor? Can you post link to the doc configuration from where you have added in your code?

Comment: I edited the question above. Now I have this toolbar which I found on this page: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar . And the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your config.js file with this:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar= [
    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ] }
];
```

Make sure that you require config.js in your application.js file:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree ./ckeditor
```

Also, CSS file should be here: **/app/assets/stylesheets/ckeditor/contents.css** not here **/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/contents.css**

After doing the changes mentioned above you can just do: `<%= f.cktext_area :img %>`.

However, if you want to pass config values in text_area directly then something like this should do:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :img, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} %>
```

or:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :img, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => {'name' => 'document', 'items' => ['Source']} } %>
```

Comment: nope, didn't work. I didn't understand, why my code with your addition doesn't work.

Comment: Same thing worked for me. Did you remove other code you had? Also make sure you have required config file in application.js

Comment: yes, I updated my code with your code. There is the old Editor again.

Comment: Just try with: `<%= f.cktext_area :img %>` don't mention all that custom config as you already have it included in application.js file. Open up your dev console on browser and try: `CKEDITOR.config.toolbar` and see if it returns just one object.

Comment: after i remove the :ckeditor => ... the editor show up right. How I can use different configs for different editors?

Comment: @Evolutio : It seems like the custom config options you were passing may not have been correct, If you want, then you will have to mention `toolbar` option in those text_areas you want with different menus.

Comment: can you give me an example in your answer, please?

Comment: I am not sure, I think it should not be considered if you are passing toolbar in the argument for ckeditor_area.

Comment: this works for me: CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_img = [
    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ] }
]; with this field: <%= f.cktext_area :img, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'img'} %>

Answer (score 1):

In view:

```
      <%= k.cktext_area :template_text, required: true, :class =>"emailBodyTemplate",  :id => "emailBodyText", placeholder: "Email Body Text", :maxlength => 255 %>
```

In app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js:

```
  CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.toolbar_mini = [
    ["Bold",  "Italic",  "Underline",  "Strike",  "-"],
    ['BulletedList','NumberedList' ],['Outdent','Indent'],
   ];
  config.toolbar = "mini";
  config.toolbarLocation = 'bottom';
  config.height = 280;       
  config.width = 620;     
  config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
}
```

Output:

[customized CKEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMMm.png)

Comment: Thanks! But it comes 3years too late :D